# How to find and replace multiple numbers with JavaScript with an UltraEdit script?

Tags: javascript, replace, find

I have `file.txt` with a measurements report containing many measuring points. The field measuring points have provisional measuring points. I want to replace now all the provisional measuring points.

How can I use the function `Find & Replace` multiples times automatically with a fixed list of the number of the fields measuring points and a list of the real measuring points?

For example:

Old numbers (provisional measuring points): 10001, 10002, 10003
New numbers (real measuring points): 251004, 251005, 251006

I have too many measuring points to do this manually.

Is it possible to have an UltraEdit script using JavaScript core as interpreter which can be run in UltraEdit to do this very quick? Or is there any other way with a text editor?

Each time the list of the real measuring points will be different. So I would like to only update the real measuring points list in the script and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

The task can be done with text editor UltraEdit with following UltraEdit script:

```
var asOldNumbers = ["10001","10002","10003"];
var asNewNumbers = ["251004","251005","251006"];

if (asOldNumbers.length == asNewNumbers.length)
{
    if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
    {
        // Define environment for this script.
        UltraEdit.insertMode();
        UltraEdit.columnModeOff();

        // Move caret to top of the active file.
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();

        // Define the parameters for the case-sensitive replaces matching whole
        // word only executed in a loop for each pair of old and new number.
        UltraEdit.ueReOn();
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.mode=0;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchCase=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchWord=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=false;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchDown=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn=false;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.preserveCase=false;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replaceAll=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replaceInAllOpen=false;

        // Run the replace all command for each pair of old and new number.
        for (var nNumberIndex = 0; nNumberIndex < asOldNumbers.length; nNumberIndex++)
        {
            UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.replace(asOldNumbers[nNumberIndex],asNewNumbers[nNumberIndex]);
        }
    }
    else UltraEdit.messageBox("There is no file opened!","SCRIPT EXECUTION ERROR");
}
else UltraEdit.messageBox("The number of old numbers is not equal the number of new numbers!","SCRIPT CODING ERROR");
```

The old and new numbers must be defined at top of the script as elements of the two string arrays.

It would be also very easy possible to read the real measuring points (new numbers) first from a file instead of having the hard-coded in the script and then run the replaces. It would be even possible to completely automate this task on template file for the measurements report and the data file with the real measuring points from the last field measurement have fixed file names and storage locations. Then a shortcut file (`.lnk` file) or a batch file could be used to run UltraEdit to open the template and the data file, do the replaces in the template file and save the modified report file with a new name by the script, and finally exit UltraEdit.